# Displaying text of the Control based on Gotfocus of other control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I am new to the WPF development.

I am developing a wpf application using MVVM pattern. I had a 'ComboBox' and a 'TextBlock' controls. On getting focus over ComboBox, the Textblock should display the tool tip of the Combobox. Combobox is binded to view model.

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbSystemVoltage" 
          ToolTip="RMS value of phase-phase voltage in kV" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SystemVoltageStore}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedSystemVoltage}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="SystemVoltageLevel"/>
```

How can I achieve this. Sample code to do so will be much helpful.

Thanks,
Sudhi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `DataTrigger` and bind per `ElementName`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">                   
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cmbSystemVoltage, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Text"
                                Value="{Binding ElementName=cmbSystemVoltage, Path=ToolTip}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
    <ComboBox Name="cmbSystemVoltage" ToolTip="RMS value of phase-phase voltage in kV" />
</StackPanel>
```

**EDIT**

If you want to show tooltip of multiple controls in a `TextBlock` I would rather subscribe to `PreviewGotKeyboardFocus Event`:

```
<Window PreviewGotKeyboardFocus="Window_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="toolTipIndicator" />
        <ComboBox ToolTip="Sample text" />
        <TextBox ToolTip="Other sample text" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

.

```
void Window_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement element = e.NewFocus as FrameworkElement;

    if (element != null && element.ToolTip != null)
    {
        this.toolTipIndicator.Text = element.ToolTip.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        this.toolTipIndicator.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the sample code. Its work's fine.                If I had a multiple Controls (ComboBox, TextBox etc.), then how can the tool tip of all the controls can be binded to one TextBlock based on the GotFocus() of a particular control?

Comment: I am using MVVM pattern to bind the control to a model. If I am right, the attached piece of code violates the MVVM pattern?

Comment: Thanks for your response and with your piece of code, I am able to get the required answer.